# nhibernate mapping, many to one

Tags: nhibernate

I have entity house which have besides other properties list of images. 
Every image will be uploaded as a single action, one by one using js crop techniques.

**Updated:**
So one house can have many images.

```
public House
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  ....
  List<Image> Images {get; set;}
}

public class Images 
{
  public House House {get; set;}
  public string Path {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}    
}
```

My db tables are following:

```
House 
 Id
 Name, ...
 On this side I don't have relation to the Image table

Image table
 Id
 HouseId
 Path
 Name
 Description
```

Is this approach ok?
How to map these objects using nhibernate orm?

Thanks

Comment: on a many to many relation ship you should have another table that makes the connection between your House and Image tables and will contain both your house id and image id. So this way your house can have many images, and an image can have many houses (if i understood your question correctly).

Comment: Just updated question. I figure it that I need many to one approach. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your entities, and then in mapping files just associate Image `HouseId` with entity of `House` class. You should have foreign key in db. As xml answer already here, I'd add fluent nhibernate way.

```
public class House
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class Image 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual House HouseEntity { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class HouseMap : ClassMap<House>
{
    public HouseMap()
    {
        Table("House");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();            
        Map(x => x.Name);
        .....
    }
}

public class ImageMap : ClassMap<Image>
{
    public ImageMap()
    {
        Table("Image");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        References(x => x.House);
        //References(x => x.House, "foreignKeyName"); There is also way to reference with specifying foreign key field
        Map(x => x.Name);
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

House.hbm.xml:

```
<bag name="Images" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
    <key column="HouseId" />
    <one-to-many class="Image" />
</bag>
```

Image.hbm.xml:

```
<id type="int" column="Id">
    <generator ... />
</id>

<many-to-one name="House" column="HouseId" cascade="none" />
```

Since you have a primary key in the images table and no *Id* property in your domain object, the id-mapping should be without the name-attribute.